# Large pdf files OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, tomcat, io, out-of-memory

I have byte array that need to be returned to frontend as a file. For this purpose I use `IOUtils.write` but if the file is bigger than 15-20MB it throw:
*failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)* and my Tomcat 7 dies.

I need to restart it to start working.

Tomcat is starting with 1.5GB RAM and dual core CPU

Here is my code:

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try{
            outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            IOUtils.write(imgbytes, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            logger.error("IO ERROR - ", ioException);
        }finally{
            if(outputStream != null){
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error closing stream - ", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the error:

```
[2016-11-21 04:07:02] ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-7] org.fwo.controller.FileController (FileController.java:43) - IO ERROR - 
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.write(IOUtils.java:1177)
    at org.fwo.controller.FileController.getFile(FileController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor403.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:408)
    ... 45 more
started
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007c1780000, 95420416, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 95420416 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid4983.log
```

Comment: I know that my memory is not enought but i search for ideas to optimize the process. Not someone to tell me "increase your RAM"...

Comment: You can get internal exception, maybe informative: Throwable t2 = t.getCause();   15MB seems not be strange number in y.2016, even in 1.5GB (32bit ?) tomcat instance

Comment: Maybe silly suggestion: there is a configuration limit for single download? Older PHP (LAMP) configurations usually had such default. I don't know what libraries do You use besides tomcat. Many years my 32b tomcats installations works without similar problem.

Comment: You ask about an `OutOfMemoryError` but in your post you show an Exception caused by a broken connection (probably caused by a request-timeout on the client side)? Those do not quite match....

Comment: Exception is caused because frontend is served by the same tomcat. And all is going down because of the `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: I've added to the post whole exception

Comment: Try `writeChunked()` (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#writeChunked(byte[],%20java.io.OutputStream) ) instead of plain `write()`. That may make sure portions of the image content are flushed regularly thus reduce the need for native memory.

Answer (score 1):

The error-message says you are running out of **native** memory, so my guess is that you are running a 32-bit JVM on windows.

A 32-bit process has 4GB of addressable memory and windows will usually reserve 2GB for itself so you are left with 2GB of user memory. Your heap takes 1.5 GB of that so there's little room left for off-heap memory where the native allocation should occur.

Solution: either reduce your heap-size to 1GB to make more room for off-heap memory or switch to a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: We are running on Digital Ocean linux machine server with 64-bit Java. Server max ram size is 2GB and we start tomcat with 1.5GB

Comment: If those 2GB are a hard limit on available virtual memory it should be the same issue, so either increase that limit or reduce your heap-size.

Comment: Ok i'll do that but i search for some other library or approach because when this piece of code is executed with large file not only the ram is going to his maximum but also the cpu is going to 70-80-100%.